# Display download progress when installing library from JFrog PyPI repository using pip

Tags: python, pip, artifactory, pypi

Normally, when installing a Python library from PyPI servers such as pypi.org or mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi using pip, a progress bar is shown:

[image: Progress bar when installing a package using pip]

However, when utilizing a JFrog PyPI repository (in our case, an in-house version 7.12.6), for each package, it seems that pip does not provide any response until the server-side download is completed, leading to a sudden and rapid delivery of the entire response. Furthermore, when working with large packages, the download progress consumes a substantial amount of time, resulting in pip client timeouts and subsequent request retries. To address this problem, it is necessary to modify the pip timeout to a significantly extended duration, particularly when installing a large package for the first time.

Is there an option available to address this problem?